# Scrolling text appears to vibrate horizontally and to be drawn multiple times

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, google-chrome

I'm building a website and I'm trying to make smooth scrolling text. The text is moving from right to left across the screen but appears to be shaking when moving.

On my Xubuntu 16.04 PC the text appears to vibrate horizontally left and right as it moves. The effect is only present when the text is moving. Looking very closely at the screen, the characters appear to be drawn multiple times on top of each other.

[image]

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04, with Google Chrome Beta (version 54). I'm using a Nvidia graphics card and I'm using the latest drivers version 361 as recommended by the Ubuntu Additional Drivers program. The problem is the same at 60Hz and 50Hz refresh rates.

On a Windows PC the text looks sharp and good. During early testing I tried CentOS with XFCE and this also had the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to make the text look sharper please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try disabling display compositing. This link talks about it but for enabling it:

http://gamblisfx.com/how-to-enable-display-compositing-on-xubuntu-14-04/

Here are the steps to do it:

1. Menu
2. Settings
3. Window Manager Tweaks
4. Compositor Tab
5. Uncheck "Enable display compositing"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried disabling and re-enabling display compositing and I can't see any difference.